# No provider for InjectionToken when using Module that uses a library that needs a Injection Token

Tags: angular

I am currently creating a library which utilizes a forked version of the Angular Library [ng-open-cv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-open-cv) (Hence the different name for the imported module). I am following the setup method provided in the instructions for that library by doing the following in the Module File of my Library:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxOpenCVModule, OpenCVOptions } from '@package_registry/ngx-open-cv';
import { OpencvDetectService } from './opencv-detect.service';

export const openCVConfig: OpenCVOptions = {
  scriptUrl: 'assets/opencv/opencv.js',
  usingWasm: false,
};

export function loadOpencvDetector(opencvDetectService: OpencvDetectService) {
  return async () => {
    await opencvDetectService.load();
  };
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    OpencvDetectService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadOpencvDetector,
      deps: [OpencvDetectService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  imports: [NgxOpenCVModule.forRoot(openCVConfig)],
  exports: [],
})
export class DetectionLibModule {}
```

For my tests I am using a `TestBed` that uses the same setup and is working as expected. To test locally if the library is working as expected I created a tarball package of the library and an Angular Application that imports my library:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, DetectionLibModule],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

There is no real logic or anything added yet and I simply want to check if the exported Module of my library is loading correctly so I can use it in the Angular Project. When I serve my application locally and try to load the page I get following error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationModule -> ApplicationRef -> ApplicationInitStatus -> InjectionToken Application Initializer -> [object Object] -> OpencvDetectService -> NgxOpenCVService -> InjectionToken Angular OpenCV Configuration Object -> InjectionToken Angular OpenCV Configuration Object -> InjectionToken Angular OpenCV Configuration Object]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Angular OpenCV Configuration Object!
```

I had the impression that due to importing `NgxOpenCVModule` in my library with the forRoot method to set it up I would not need to do anything else in my UI Angular Project in order to keep the setup effort to a minimum.

Am I doing this entirely wrong, miss something or what could be causing this problem in the first place? I'm not that experienced with Angular Libraries yet that's why I would really like the input of a more experienced dev.

The other posts on here with a similar issue have not been helping much.

Comment: It seems like this module require an InjectionToken, perhaps when try to inject the object openCVConfig, you should use a particular token exported by the lib. Don't you have any example?

Comment: The object I pass is correct, since I already used the ng-open-cv lib in other projects. The problem only appears when I use it in my library and then import its module in a separate Angular Application.

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps you should use forChild instead of forRoot in your library

Comment: @SergioRinaudo I'm doing a workaround now since I can't get it up and running. I directly install ngx-open-cv in my application and add it to the imports of AppModule there. The downside is I have to manually copy the assets from my library into the application but due to that I can also freely exchange the opencv version per application.

The service is loading normally and can be used. Requires some extra effort and my lib is not completely independent but better than not working at all.